# I've never *been* sailing

Tags: perfect-aspect

Murphy's grammar (Unit 63D) explains the usage of the structure **go -ing**: *go swimming*, *go climbing* etc. It gives a number of examples:

> How often do you *go* swimming?
>
> When did you last *go* shopping?
>
> I've never **been** sailing. (!!)

What is **been** doing there? To me it should be "*I've never sailed*." Or if we use the verb *go* -- "*I've never gone sailing*." Because there is no **be** in the **go -ing** structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are quite right. This sentence does not belong in a discussion of the *go VERBing* construction. The sentence which should replace it is

> I’ve never **gone** sailing.

Note, however, that this is an editorial mistake, not a grammatical one. The sentence “I've never been sailing” is both idiomatic and formally grammatical. With *never*, *have been VERBing* is not merely the negative of the present perfect progressive; it expresses exactly the same thing as *have gone VERBing*.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the question has rearranged the sentence order.  One would say:

> How often do you go swimming?
>   When did you last go shopping?
>   How often do you go sailing?
>   When did you last go sailing?

Or Even:

> How often do you swim?
>   How often do you shop?
>   How often do you sail?

Likewise:

> I've never been sailing
>   I've never been shopping
>   I've never been sailing

The "been [verb]" construction is necessary because you are making a predicate nominative which calls for the infinitive form.